# Mvc Method name must be a string

Tags: php

I have problem and i dont have idea how to slove this.

Problem on this line code:

```
   public function ExecuteAction() {
        return $this->{$this->action}();
    }
```

All other work fine controller success loaded but i have fatal error for this.

> Fatal error: Method name must be a string in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Workplace\MVC\lib\BaseController.php on line 27

Check my code:

**Index.php**

```
$fController = new FController($_GET);
$controller = $fController->CreateController();
$controller->ExecuteAction();
```

**Fcontorler**

```
   public function createController() 
   {
        if(class_exists($this->controller)) {
            $parent = class_parents($this->controller);
            if(in_array('BaseController', $parent)) {
                if(method_exists($this->controller, $this->action)) {
                    return new $this->controller($this->action, $this->url);
                }else {
                    echo "Method no exists";
                }
            }else {
                echo "Bad Controller";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Controller ". $this->controller . " class no exists";
        }
   }
```

**BaseController**

```
abstract class BaseController {

    protected $urlvalues;
    protected $action;

    /*
     * Construct
     * 
     * @param string  $action
     * @param array   $url
     * 
     */

    public function __construct($action, $urlvalues) {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->urlvalues = $urlvalues;
    }

    /*
     * Execute acction
     * 
     */

    public function ExecuteAction() {
        return $this->{$this->action}();
    }
```

> localhost/Workplace/MVC/index.php?controller=hello&action=say&id=5

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->action)` outputs if placed in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

> var_dump($controller); object(Hello)#2 (2) { ["urlvalues":protected]=> NULL ["action":protected]=> NULL }

The error is triggered because you are trying to use `NULL` while the interpreter is expecting a string.

As your `var_dump` shows, `$this->action` is `NULL` therefore the string interpolation `$this->{$this->action}();` is translated to `$this->{NULL}();` that cannot be called.

Comment: Check full source. http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/9/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-3-controllers